# Laravel not running try catch block

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Ive run into a little issue.

Im calling a method using the following

```
$this->testConnection($request->all());
```

The method looks like so

```
private function testConnection($data)
{
    try {
        $conn = ftp_connect($data['host']);
        if (false === $conn) {
            throw new Exception('Cant connect');
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->route('create')->withInput()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Update: It seems the ftp_connect PHP function isn't working and its not returning any errors

Im using Laravel 5.3

Any help would be grand.

Cheers,

Comment: try `throw new \Exception('Cant connect');`

Comment: @aleksejjj ..No luck, still not running the try block

Comment: so, you mean you call `testConnection($data)` correct, but nothing run only inside `try` block?

Comment: @aleksejjj ... Yes, the method is being called, but the try catch block isnt being run

Comment: It's sounds strange. So `testConnection($data)
{
dd('here');
    try {` will works but  `testConnection($data)
{
    try { dd('here');` doesn't?

Comment: Are you calling `$this->testConnection($request->all());` from the same class? The problem could be declaring it as `private`

Comment: hmmm, interesting ... It seems the problem seems to be the ftp_connect ... Ill update my question

Comment: What about `if (!$conn)`? Yes, I know it must return `FALSE` but you can try this way.

Comment: Does ftp_connect require anything special to be setup in the php.ini or anything like that? ... Im running Homestead

Comment: As far as I know it works by default. Can you try example from php docs? `$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or dd("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");` Will it die?

Comment: @aleksejjj .. Really weird ... It dies outside the try block, but if i put it inside the try block it doesnt :S

Comment: I tried your code with `$conn = ftp_connect('http://ftp.mozilla.org/');` and was redirected to route('create') as expected

Comment: @aleksejjj what happens if you enter a website that doesnt exist, thats what i need to catch

Comment: @BigJobbies Hmm.. I got exception for any host. So, try/catch works correct for me. Important notes: I doesn't using Homestead, but I think no matter for your try-catch trouble.

Comment: I seem to have found the issue, i was missing the use Exception; ... I will create an answer

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this was that i was missing

```
use Exception;
```